# Can terraform produce a plan for a code change without a state file?

Tags: debugging, terraform

When there is a team using terraform to manage cloud resources (via a shared git repository), and most members do not have direct individual access to the state file (for security reasons), what practices are available for testing and debugging change (e.g. feature) proposals prior to circulating pull requests?

Without a state file (or admin credentials), can terraform locally produce a speculative plan for the *changes* with respect to a base commit? Or would it be necessary to produce separate speculative plans (for the main branch and the new feature branch) then perform a *diff*? Like, can another speculative plan be used in place of a state file? Or is the standard workflow to keep pushing unfinished work to a temporary remote branch, with continuous-integration pipelines configured to automatically generate plans against the actual state?

Comment: How would Terraform produce a plan if it does not know what the current state is?

Comment: @MarkoE if you don't have state file than plan would be `create everything`.

Comment: And what if some stuff is already there? :)

Comment: "Or is the standard workflow to keep pushing unfinished work to a temporary remote branch, with continuous-integration pipelines configured to automatically generate plans against the actual state?" Yes; with a webhook.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you intend is to create workflow like this:

1. Junior DevOps commits code with proposal of some feature which needs some kind of resource in cloud. (we don't trust them enough yet, so he can't provision it resource by himself)
2. CI is making some checks about the code (checkov, terraform verify, etc.)
3. **CI tests** are passing -> **we'll come back here**
4. Code is reviewed by senior Devops and gets accepted
5. CI executes `terraform apply`

If so, let's focus on question...

### What does it mean ***`to test`*** terraform changes?

Depending on case it could be:

1. `terraform plan` prints valid plan
2. `terraform apply` works on ***test*** environment (separated from production, with empty state file - remember to clean this after tests)

   - this case also allows to run some real tests (e2e, simple curl, integration tests, etc.)

Of course second one is a lot better, but not always you can (or it makes sense) to create test resources. Usually it can be made by setting some different name in resource.

---

What test probably doesn't mean is to apply changes on your production.

Diff from plan also isn't best 'test' available since also two `terraform plan` run one after another can differ.